# Node JS Express Ports

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am using redis to send a session cookie from PHP to Node/Express. The only way I seem to be able to access the cookie in my server.js code is if I create an empty file on the client and include it like this with the port:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.nodetest.com:8080/empty.js"></script>`

If I don't include this on the client, I cannot access the cookie data on the node server.

My requirement is that I don't need to send the cookie back to the client. Only to access it in the server.js to authenticate a user against the DB.

Here is the contents of my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(8081),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        // this is the default prefix used by redis-session-php
        prefix: 'session:php:'
    }),
    // use the default PHP session cookie name
    name: 'PHPSESSID',
    secret: 'node.js rules'
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session);
    req.session.nodejs = 'Hello from node.js!';
    res.send();
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
        console.log('joining room', room);
        socket.join(room);
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: How/when is the cookie generated by PHP and returned to the client? How is server.js triggered in the client side? I guess you have a PHP script that authenticates a user and next renders a page that has a javascript that connects to socket.io implemented in server.js? Is it correct? Can you give a little bit more detail on your setup.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm using predis and https://github.com/TheDeveloper/redis-session-php/ to store the cookie in redis and retrieve in node. The issue I believe is that the express app is listening on port 8080 but for some reason the cookie is only accessible if some request is made by the client using port 8080. I have some example code on dropbox if that helps?

Comment: Yes, some example code could help. You can post some snippets in your question or give us a link.

Comment: Here's the code: https://db.tt/HBi1ljuZ You can run it by creating a vhost called `dev.nodetest.com` start a redis server and run `node server.js` in a console. It should log the cookie to console. Then if you edit index.php and remove the request to emptyfile.js You will see that the cookie is no longer logged.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the session info in the express middleware below:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session);
    req.session.nodejs = 'Hello from node.js!';
    res.send();
});
```

This middleware is ONLY invoked when you make a normal http request (interpret it as express requests). When you make transactions with **socket.io** the above code is never executed (eg. connect a socket, send a message, disconnect, etc).

**index.php** generates a cookie and a page that contains a script that connects to **socket.io** and emits a message to it. When you do just that, the above middleware is not executed. But, when you generate a "normal request" the above middleware will be executed.
That's why the middleware is executed when you include the script **empty.js** with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.nodetest.com:8080/empty.js"></script>
```

In practice this would be executed for any request, eg. *http://dev.nodetest.com:8080/foobar* or *http://dev.nodetest.com:8080/anotherfoobar*. The url do not need to point to existing files. Any URL on port 8080 will invoke the middleware. BUT SOCKET.IO REQUESTS WILL NEVER TRIGGER YOUR TESTING MIDDLEWARE.

**EDIT**
There are libraries that may help you working with sessions in socket.io. [sessio.socket.io](https://www.npmjs.org/package/session.socket.io) seems to be adequate for your scenario.

Comment: That should be ok as long as I can pass the session in to the socket code when the page is loaded from apache. What do you suggest I do? Will using proxies solve the issue?

Comment: Or is there a way to securely retrieve the session using sockets?

Comment: Yes, you can use https://www.npmjs.org/package/session.socket.io. I have updated my answer.

Comment: That repo does not seem to be maintained for over a year and doesn't look like it will work with express 4. Here is a fork that seems to be more actively maintained https://github.com/eiriklv/session.socket.io. I'll take a look at it now..

Comment: If you have time, could you provide some example code getting the PHPSESSID?

Comment: I was trying to get it working but the example still looks it is made for express 3.x